# How to embed a Facebook page wall, into a website, with all actions of "Like", "Comment" on posts?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to `embed` a Facebook page wall into a website? Without using Graph API?

I want to have the wall exactly as styled from Facebook, with all actions to **Like**, **Comment** and **Share** but from my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry but there is no way to easy reproduce your wall on your website. You can easily get contents (but it will not reflect the facebook's wall as some content is filtered), using facebook's [javascript sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) or [graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api), but you won't be able to add universal **like** button using javascript sdk for every posts, as facebook requires to like some objects (like pages) directly with their [like social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like).

You can check a lot of facebook widgets you can easily implement on your website using [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) on the [fbrell application](http://fbrell.com/examples).

Happy facebook programming!

Answer (score 1):

Based on these requirements, would an `iframe` produce the desired effect?  Maybe even a regular `frame`?  (I haven't used those in a *long* time, so I don't remember if there's some restriction that would prevent loading external content with them).

When you say you want these actions "from your website" what exactly do you mean?  Do you just want to wrap the Facebook content with your own (in a frame) or do you want to actually do something locally with these actions, intercepting them somehow?

Comment: That won't do anything, just an empty iframe. I have tried doing that, also u dont have a direct link to facebook wall.

Comment: Take care in iFrame-ing another website: http://www.plagiarismtoday.com/2009/04/07/is-the-diggbar-content-theft/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use FBML. or custom code from for using Graph API, i dont think you can do it any other way. look up facebook documentaion for details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can embed the same wall, yet you can use paste your wall's contents on your webpage,

If you want Share, Like and comment button to perform action on your webstie then you have to create your own db and user management

But...

Share, Like and Comment buttons which will effect your original wall in facebook is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

double think.  I have been working on a Wall Feed for Pages for some time now, what you are looking for can be done, but you would need to use the Graph API to accomplish..

Sample Here http://shawnsspace.com/plugins/wallfeed.php  Likes, Commenting is disabled.
Emulates the Wall for http://facebook.com

I used a combination of Graph API "PHP-SDK 3.1.1", "Javascript SDK".  This can be done with pure client side Javascript though.